# Using determinant approach to find values of a and b for a matrix system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, systems-of-equations

Use the determinant approach to find all values of a and b for the system Ax=k... (system found in picture link)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & a & b \\
0 & b & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2-b \end{bmatrix}$$

[image: Picture]

Comment: What is "the determinant approach of Ex 135"?

Comment: Using the determinant to find the variables and when (for example) b + 2 = 0, b = -2, therefore replacing b with -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First compute $det(A)$ by expanding along the first column: $det(A)=a-b^2$

(a) Provided $det(A)=a-b^2\ne0$ we have that $A$ is invertible, so there will be a unique solution. We can compute the solution by using Cramer's rule, etc.

$$x=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}\color{blue}{2}&0&1\\\color{blue}{1}&a&b\\\color{blue}{2-b}&b&1\end{vmatrix}}{a-b^2}=\frac{2(a-b^2)+(b-a(2-b))}{a-b^2}=\frac{ab+b-2b^2}{a-b^2}$$ and similarly for $y,z$.

(b) There are no solutions if $det(A)=0$ and the equations are inconsistent.

$$det(A)=0 \implies a=b^2$$
so the second and third equations reduce to
$$\begin{bmatrix}b^2&b\\b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2-b\end{bmatrix}$$

Equations are inconsistent if:
$1\ne b(2-b) \implies b^2-2b+1\ne0 \implies (b-1)^2\ne0 \implies b\ne1,a=b^2$

(c) There is more than one solution if the equations are consistent, i.e. $b=1,a=b^2=1$ for which two solutions are:

$x=1,y=0,z=1$ and $x=2,y=1,z=0$